# react native expo deep linking not working for android

Tags: android, react-native

I create app with react native expo and added deep linking. Config looks like this in `app.config.ts`:

```
 android: {
          package: 'android-package-name',
          intentFilters: [
            {
              action: 'VIEW',
              autoVerify: true,
              data: [
                {
                  scheme: 'https',
                  host: '*my-app.com',
                  pathPrefix: '/claim',
                },
              ],
              category: ['BROWSABLE', 'DEFAULT'],
            },
          ],
        },
```

I do have the plugin mentioned here [React native expo deep linking with android](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/deep-linking/#handling-app-links-on-android-with-expo-dev-client) and it's added in `app.json` plugins.

Then on my website i do have the needed `./well-known/assetslinks.json` file with following config:

```
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "android-package-name",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [...sha256_cert_fingerprints]
  }
}
```

And when i can the mobile application is not opening it behave like is not installed. Any ideas please